# Mac Os LaTex won't compile my bibliography BibTex

Tags: bibtex, mac

I am writing a paper on LaTex on Mac, and have written a bibliography called `bibliography.tex` to cite my paper with. I have

```
\biblography{biblography}
\biblographystyle{plain}
```

at the bottom of my paper for it to compile with LaTex but whenever I run BibTex to compile `bibliography.tex` I receive the error message 
`bibliography.aux` not found.

And when I try to run the BibTex within my paper I get an error message

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014)
The top-level auxiliary file: dissertation.aux
I couldn't open database file biblography.bib
---line 12 of file dissertation.aux
 : \bibdata{biblography
 :                     }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: plain.bst
I found no database files---while reading file dissertation.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "WingraSchools"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

I don't know what I doing wrong as why it neither will compile, please help!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) always post full minimal examples. What is the rest of that document? (3) Did you run LaTeX on the `.tex` file first? It goes LaTeX, bibtex, LaTeX, LaTeX. (4) Is anything actually being cited? (see why (2) is important)

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The bibtex entries should be in a file with `.bib` extensions, they should be in the file `bibliography.bib`

Comment: The error message you're getting -- "I couldn't open database file biblography.bib" -- should tell you what you need to do: rename the bibliography file from `bibliography.tex` to `bibliography.bib`. This error message is not related to the operating system (e.g., MacOS) you may be using.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a type in the argument to \bibliography